# Polymorphism and properties

Tags: delphi, freepascal

I'm trying to use polymorphism and create a property that should return different types depending on what type of object it is.

Why is there this compiler warning for the code below:

[Warning: Constructing a class "TTimeField" with abstract method "SetValue"]

More important, how can I make this work so Value can be assigned a TDateTime when a TTimeField is created? As it is, there is a message about "type mismatch".

```
  TBaseField = class
  private
    function  GetValue: string; virtual; abstract;
    procedure SetValue(AValue: string); virtual; abstract;
  public
    property  Value: string read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;

  { TTimeField }

  TTimeField = class(TBaseField)
  private
    FValue :  TDateTime;
    function  GetValue: TDateTime; override;
    procedure SetValue(AValue: TDateTime); override;
  public
    property  Value: TDateTime read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;
```

implementation

```
function TTimeField.GetValue: TDateTime;
begin
  Result:= FValue;
end;

procedure TTimeField.SetValue(AValue: TDateTime);
begin
  FValue:= AValue;
end;
```

EDIT: Below, with the use of strings I achieved the functionality needed, but if the code above had worked it had meant a gain in performance.

```
TBaseField = class
private
  procedure SetStrValue(AValue: string); virtual; abstract;
  function  GetStrValue: string; virtual; abstract;
public
  property  AsString: string read GetStrValue write SetStrValue;
end;

TTimeField = class(TBaseField)
private
  FValue :  TDateTime;
  function  GetStrValue: string; override;
  procedure SetStrValue(AValue: string); override;
public
  property  AsString: string read GetStrValue write SetStrValue;
end;

function TTimeField.GetStrValue: string;
begin
  Result:= DateTimeToStr(FValue);
end;

procedure TTimeField.SetStrValue(AValue: string);
begin
  FValue:=StrToDateTime(AValue);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism is used with methods rather than properties. You can define a property that has virtual getter and setter methods, and then use polymorphism on those getter and setter methods.

However, polymorphic methods are not allowed to change the type of the arguments or the return value. Why not?

Well, suppose we write this code:

```
type
  TMyBaseClass = class
  public
    procedure Foo(Arg: string); virtual;
  end;

....

var
  obj: TMyBaseClass;

....

obj.Foo('bar');
```

One of the tenets of polymorphism is that `obj` can be an instance of `TMyBaseClass` or indeed any class derived from `TMyBaseClass`. The compiler does not need to know the actual type of `obj`, only that it is derived from `TMyBaseClass`. The type is only known at runtime, and polymorphic virtual method despatch ensures that the derived method is called.

This means that it would make no sense for `Foo` to accept arguments of any type other than that declared when the virtual method was first introduced.

What you need is something called a variant type. A variant type is one that can represent many different types. For instance, any decent variant type will be able to represent integers, floating point values, strings, dates and times and so on. In Delphi you would use something like the COM `Variant` type, or the more recently added `TValue`. In Free Pascal, I'm not so sure what the prevailing variant type is.

Comment: Plus, OP might be confusing polymorphism with generic types.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have modified the code to use strings as you can see above. But Variants would perhaps give a performance gain over strings, what do you think?

Comment: I don't much care for storing the date as text. Scope for errors when converting. I'd be more concerned about correctness than performance. I can't comment on performance because I don't know what your performance constraints are.

Comment: Alright, the Variant will get a chance, if only because I never used it. Could be interesting. Doing it with strings is fast enough and probably the variant is faster than that.

Comment: ISTM that this should not be polymorphic at all. The rest can easily be polymorphic through virtual methods, but this is the part that should not be virtual at all. How are you going to retrieve a value? Polymorphism means that you **don't** have to know, since the method call is the same for all classes, base or one of the derived ones. So, you must know the type you are retrieving or setting anyway. Then you don't need polymorphism. But if you want a unified interface, so you can, say, store or print, etc. all versions the same way, think of interfaces instead of class inheritance.

Comment: Variants are basically working with FPC, like usual, current versions of FPC are probably more compatible than old versions of Delphi. (like D7) The only known problem afaik is that olevariants dynamic dispatch with item[] arrays are not always 100%

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you're not actually overriding any method; your new method has a different signature. Therefore it is actually an overload. In your example, having `TBaseField` doesn't really help you in any way. The subclass doesn't use any of its methods, nor does it provide any extra functionality.

Polymorphism is about varying implementations for a given interface (as in method signatures) without the caller needing to knowing about that. 
Looking at your example, it might just be that you're not necessarily looking for polymorphism, but rather for a way to implement similar methods/properties for various data types with as little code as possible. That's where generics usually prove more useful.

Say that all field classes need to store a value of their own type, which should be possible to set and retrieve. Then you can define a generic `TField<T>` where `T` is a "placeholder" for the type of data that the field should work with. You will be able to give it a getter and setter, as well as a property, which will be generic too. As such, you'll only need to define them once for all kinds of fields you'll end up using. These methods may contain whatever logic is shared by all fields. You may, however, still subclass a generic type to add specific functionality to a certain type, or to hide the fact that you rely on generics.

A simple example:

```
type
  TField<T> = class
  private
    FValue: T;
  protected
    function GetValue: T; virtual;
    procedure SetValue(const AValue: T); virtual;
  public
    property Value: T read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;

  TDateTimeField = TField<TDateTime>;

  TTrimmingStringField = class(TField<string>);
  protected
    function SetValue(const AValue: string); override;
  end;

  // Now use these fields as you'd expect

implementation

{ TField<T> }

function TField<T>.GetValue: T;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;

procedure TField<T>.SetValue(const AValue: T);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
end;

{ TTrimmingStringField }

procedure TTrimmingStringField.SetValue(const AValue: string);
begin
  inherited SetValue(Trim(AValue));
end;
```

Comment: Can you explain how generics would help. I must admit I can't see how that would fit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I expanded my answer a bit to address that.

Comment: Try implementing that. Try writing a generic method that can return an integer or a string. You'll almost certainly end up using a variant type, likely TValue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What I'm proposing is really very basic. Added the code so you can see what I mean. The premise is that polymorphism, although stated as such, is not the actual goal here.

Comment: Upvoted. I dont have much experience with generics yet, but this could have been a very good solution. In this particular case I can't use it because PascalScript doesn't seem to support generics and the data must be accessible from there.

Comment: @Rimfire I'm not sure if that is an issue. As long as the class is declared in Delphi code, like `TDateTimeField` above, it will most probably look like an ordinary class to PascalScript. That is exactly what I meant by "hiding the fact that you rely on generics." Generic classes only exist until compile time; the compiler will instantiate/expand them to form the required ordinary classes.

Comment: So just because the Unit Importer can't parse code with generics in it, that doesn't mean PascalScript cant run the code.. Never thought about that! Will try to write the import file manually and see if I can make that work.